# Microsoft Graph Excel Comments Possible?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am working on a project where I am using the Microsoft Graph API.
I am trying to dynamically insert comments into an excel document.
I see this can be done from with the Excel JS API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-comments

However, can this be done from within the Graph API?
I see that we can grab comment info but I don't see anything for adding a comment.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/workbookcomment?view=graph-rest-1.0

Has anybody been able to accomplish this?

Thanks,
Brad

Comment: There is no create workbookcomment endpoint. Please raise a feature request in the [Microsoft Graph Feedback Forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests) so that the product team may add this feature in the future.

Comment: Moving this to Answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no create workbookcomment endpoint. Please raise a feature request in the [Microsoft Graph Feedback Forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests) so that the product team may add this feature in the future.